# Reference an attribute/parameter in a regex expression

Tags: regex, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have two types of xml file (pom.xml and descriptors) that I want to join into a single dataset. There is no common key, so I'm taking the two directories and using the project name fragment before the underscore.

I have two variables to work with:

```
repository="/home/qeebrato/Git/ddt"
uri="file:/home/qeebrato/Git/ddt/eventhandlers_repeatlookup/src/main/resources/descriptors/eventhandlers_repeatlookup.descriptor"
```

I want "eventhandlers".

To get this project fragment I have

```
<xsl:attribute name="project"><xsl:value-of select='replace(@uri,"(.*)@repository(^_).*_(^$)","$2")'/></xsl:attribute>
```

The webpages on XSLT string processing I've seen make no mention of using identifiers inside the regex.

Comment: The regular expression arguments to replace or tokenize are just strings, so you can construct them as any other strings with e.g. `concat` if you want to build them based on a combination of other strings and variables or nodes.

Comment: The concat workaround did it, thanks. I'm still unsure whether I can escape a string in XSLT to include a attribute/variable?

Comment: I don't see why `concat` is a workaround. If you move to XSLT/XPath 3 you can also use the `||` operator e.g.`'foo' || @uri || 'bar'` https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/#id-string-concat-expr but there is no string interpolation in the form of PHP's "foo$varbar".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Building a string to use in a `replace()` regex

The `replace()` function takes at least three arguments: the input string, the regex pattern to match, and the replacement.

In your sample: 
* The input string is the `uri` attribute on some element.
* The pattern seems to include the value of the `repository` attribute on this same element.
* The replacement is just the second match in the pattern.

The main problem you mention in your post is in the pattern -- you want to include the value of the `repository` attribute.  To do so, we can follow Martin Honnen's advice from his comment, and use `concat()` to construct the string:

```
concat("(.*)", @repository, "(^_).*_(^$)")
```

#### Troubleshooting problems with a regex

I created a simple test XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test repository="/home/qeebrato/Git/ddt" uri="file:/home/qeebrato/Git/ddt/eventhandlers_repeatlookup/src/main/resources/descriptors/eventhandlers_repeatlookup.descriptor"/>
```

And a simple XSL file to apply to this test, using the fixed `replace()` call above:

```
<xsl:template match="test">
    <xsl:value-of select='replace(@uri,concat("(.*)", @repository, "(^_).*_(^$)"),"$2")'/>
</xsl:template>
```

Running this XSL against this XML gives me:

```
file:/home/qeebrato/Git/ddt/eventhandlers_repeatlookup/src/main/resources/descriptors/eventhandlers_repeatlookup.descriptor
```

... which is identical to the original value of the `uri` attribute.  Ultimately, your `replace()` doesn't do anything.

From [the W3C specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath-functions-20101214/#func-replace):

> Summary: The function returns the `xs:string` that is obtained by replacing each non-overlapping substring of `$input` that matches the given `$pattern` with an occurrence of the `$replacement` string.

A careful reading of this, and testing, clarifies that the function returns `$input` if `$pattern` is valid, but doesn't match anything.

Let's deconstruct your `$pattern` regex.

- `(.*)` -- zero or more characters:
  This alone could match the whole string.
- `@repository` -- the value of the `repository` attribute: `/home/qeebrato/Git/ddt`
  This matches the first part of the actual path in your `$input` string.
- `(^_)` -- this is where things go funny.
  I *think* you meant to use `[^_]` instead, with square brackets, which indicates a character that is not an underscore.
  However, `(^_)` with round parentheses translates to a capturing match of an underscore at the start of `$input`, or at the start of a line, depending on your mode.  The `replace()` function defaults to `^` matching the start of the whole string.  Since there is no underscore at the start of your `$input` string, this `$pattern` fails to match -- so the function just returns `$input` as-is.

#### Getting what you need

You say, *I want "eventhandlers"*.  If you mean, *I want to extract this portion of the string*, here's the `replace` statement you'd need to get that as output:

```
replace(@uri, concat(".*", @repository, "/([^_]+)_.*$"), "$1")
```

Breaking this down:

- `.*` matches zero or more characters.
- `@repository` plugs in the string value of that attribute: `/home/qeebrato/Git/ddt`
- `/` since we need another path separator.
- `([^_]+)` in round parens to capture, and what we capture is `+` one or more characters that `[^_]` are not an underscore.
- `_.*$` matches the following underscore, and then anything else until the end of the string.

We replace all that with `$1`, our first (and only) captured match, producing `eventhandlers`.

#### Notes

- You mention in your post that you *have two variables*.  However, you use the `@` symbol in your `replace()` call, which specifies an attribute value.

  If `repository` and `uri` are actually variables (defined in your XSL using `<xsl:variable>` elements) or parameters (defined using `<xsl:param>`), then you need to use `$` instead of `@`.
- If you're working with regular expressions a lot, it will likely prove very worthwhile to use a regular expression tool, such as [Regex Tester](http://www.regextester.com/) (online), [RegExr](http://regexr.com/) (online), or [RegexBuddy](https://www.regexbuddy.com/) (for pay application; apparently made by the same guy that maintains http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

  *(Full disclosure: I have used RegexBuddy for years, but otherwise have no relationship with any of these regex websites or tool developers).*